# how to wait for first query results and then execute another query in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm making an app in angular & node.js. At a certain point of code I need to  execute `INSERT` query and then get back `insertId` and then make another `INSERT` into another table along with above `insertId`. But i'm always getting `0` as insertId because it does not wait for first query to be executed due to its async nature. So I need a work around to wait for first query results and then execute second query. My code looks like below.

```
insert_users_query = `INSERT INTO users xxxxxx`;
connection.query(insert_users_query, (err, result)=>{
    var user_id = result.insertId;
});

second_query = `INSERT INTO another_table (user_id) VALUES('${user_id}')`;
connection.query(linked_accounts_query, (err, result)=>{
// this query saves 0  as user_id in table.
});
```

I think this can be done via `promises`. But as I'm beginner in this stuff and read an article on `Promises` too but I can't figure out a simple solution. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: hope this is just typo that `second_query` and  `linked_accounts_query` are different.

Answer (score 1):

You can do same by.

```
insert_users_query = `INSERT INTO users xxxxxx`;
connection.query(insert_users_query, (err, result)=>{// query 1( getting insertId as result.insertId)
    if(err){
     //handle error
    }else{
    var user_id = result.insertId; // using insertId
    second_query = `INSERT INTO another_table (user_id) VALUES('${user_id}')`;
    connection.query(linked_accounts_query, (err, result2)=>{//query2
  // this query saves 0  as user_id in table.
   }
 });



});
```

This is done by using callback you can use `await` for the same.
This is bit simpler basically we will get `err,result` as object after the execution of  query1 and then we can run another query using `err,result` of query1 in query1.

Comment: I have already tried this before posting question. In this way second query wont get to execute at all.

Comment: may be `linked_accounts_query` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use async/await for this as well instead of calling 2nd query inside 1st as it creates mess when number of queries increases.

But since `connection.query` returns a callback we need to wrap it inside a promise.

```
async function main(){ 
  try{
    const insert_users_query = `INSERT INTO users xxxxxx`;
    const result = await queryDb(insert_users_query);
    let user_id = result.insertId;
    const linked_accounts_query = `INSERT INTO another_table (user_id) VALUES('${user_id}')`;
    await queryDb(linked_accounts_query);
  }
  catch(e){
    //catch error
  }
}
```

You can call this generic `queryDb` function returning `promise` for all the queries.

```
function queryDb(query){
  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
      connection.query(query, (err, result)=>{
          if (err){
              return reject( err );
          }
          resolve( result );
      });
  })
}
```

Comment: hi @helping hand, Thanks for your time and reply! I was away for couple of days and just checked your solution. Unfortunately it doesn't worked. Error appears `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` and I tried to define function `querydb` as `async function querydb(query)` as well as `let querydb = async function (query)` and neither worked. Any further help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: add name async to the function in which above try catch code is called.